# What is object.classname kind?

Tags: c++

Consider this class:

```
struct Foo {
  int bar;
  Foo(){}
  Foo(int a) {
    bar = a;
  }
};
```

Now, I have two ways to access member `bar`:

```
Foo foo(1234);
cout << foo.bar << endl;
cout << foo.Foo::bar << endl;
```

But I don't know what is `foo.Foo`'s kind:

```
using namespace foo.Foo; //error, because foo.Foo is not a namespace
foo.Foo baz; //error, because foo.Foo is not a class
```

Please tell me what is `foo.Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.Foo` isn't anything. `Foo::bar` is the `bar` member of the `Foo` class, and `foo.Foo::bar` is the `bar` member of the `Foo` class in the instance `foo`.

That syntax is generally used if you have name conflicts with multiple inheritance. Consider this example:

```
struct A{int bar;};
struct B{int bar;};
struct C:A,B{};
```

Now the following code is ambiguous:

```
C c;
std::cout << c.bar;
```

We need to say which `bar` we want:

```
C c;
std::cout << c.A::bar;
std::cout << c.B::bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not (foo.Foo)::bar, it's foo.(Foo::bar) and Foo::bar is bar

This can be usefull in this example :

```
struct A{
    int i;
};
struct B{
    int i;
};

class C : public A, B{
};

int main(){
    C c;
    c.i = 0;   // request for member 'i' is ambiguous
}
```

you should use namespaces A and B to access the data, `A::i` or `B::i`

Answer (score 0):

Members of struct are public by default , so you can access memebrs with dot and well as scope resolution (::) operator.So foo.Foo::bar is same as foo.bar.